# ?eval("len(some number)") returns maximum of 29

Tags: vba, eval

Tested with Microsoft Visual Basic for applications 7.0.1628

When I try to execute (directly):

```
?eval("len(12345678901234567890123456789)")
```

it returns 29 which is correct.

```
?eval("len(123456789012345678901234567890)")
```

should return 30 but returns 20.

```
?eval("len('123456789012345678901234567890')")
```

returns 30 correctly.

So the question is:
If

```
?len(12341)
```

returns an error because it needs a string, why does eval make it work but only till the 29th number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not with Eval but with Len.

For anything other than Strings or Variants, Len() acts like the sizeof() operator in C, i.e. it returns the number of bytes used to store the variable:

For example:

```
Public Function test()

Dim intTest As Integer
Dim lngTest As Long

  intTest = 12345
  Debug.Print "Len (Int): " & Len(intTest)
  lngTest = 12345
  Debug.Print "Len (Long): " & Len(lngTest)

End Function
```

Outputs:

Len (Int): 2

Len (Long): 4

Comment: But why does it return 29 correctly then in my first example? It should return an error as it does in the 4th example. And why does it return 20 in the second example? So eval must have to do something with it.

Comment: My VBA says it's 7.0.1637 and Len(12345) does not error in it, it gives 2 for an Integer or 4 for a Long Integer, as per my example function above. I also can't replicate your 29. What I *can* do is make your second example give 21 if I add enough digits to it. I'm using Office Home & Business 2010, 32-bit, on this particular machine.

Comment: You have to know, that I did not write a function, but enter it in the "Immediate Window". Maybe that is an answer? I'll check it.

Comment: Perhaps you could give a fuller example of what you're trying to achieve and then it will be easier to give you a solution. It's currently difficult to understand why you are using eval or, indeed, why you are trying to find the length of a number.

Comment: In our ERP-software we are checking the contents of a field where a user can enter information using the eval()-function. As this fields can also contain other functions, one of our customers that is producing signs entered the function len([link to the field]) as a default value to get the number of letters of the term entered in the field back, because the number of letters makes the price of the sign in this case. That's where this error occured.

Comment: Then it is your customer who does not understand that Len() for numerical values does not return the number of digits but the space required to store them. If they enclose the number in the Len() with "" then it should work correctly.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I did. What I could not understand is why it went up to 29 and afterwards stayed at 20. But now I got an idea. Thank you :)